# Select stuff where exists in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I want to count the number of records with duplicated values, and then get all sorts of other data related to it. Like this:

```
SELECT Id, Name, PhoneNumber, Code, CodeCount from Person
WHERE Code IN (SELECT Code, COUNT(Code) AS CodeCount
               FROM Person
               GROUP BY Code
               HAVING COUNT(Code) > 1);
```

But I get the error `The columns in the subquery do not match.`

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Note:  this doesn't work on SQL Server CE, but it does work on SQL Server 2005+.

Another way to approach this is using window functions:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, count(*) over (partition by code) as cnt
      from person p
     ) p
where cnt > 1;
```

Because the `in` requires both an aggregation and a join (implicitly because of the `in`), this version will often have better performance.  It can also make use of an index on `person(code)`.

Comment: Doesn't work for me using Sql Server Compact... probably unsupported

Answer (score 1):

You are doing "`Code IN (...)`", but the subquery is returning two columns instead of one.

Remove the additional column from the subquery.

You don't need to return the count. The `HAVING` clause will work just the same even if you don't return that column in the subquery.

```
SELECT Id, Name, PhoneNumber, Code, CodeCount from Person
WHERE Code IN (SELECT Code
           FROM Person
           GROUP BY Code
           HAVING COUNT(Code) > 1);
```

Comment: Okay this at least works without error if I exclude `CodeCount`, but I need it... it shows the number of dupes. How do I include that in the results?

Answer (score 1):

This will work on you

```
    SELECT Id, Name, PhoneNumber, Code, COUNT(Code) AS 'CodeCount' 
    from Person WHERE Code IN (SELECT Code FROM Person) 
    GROUP BY Id, Name, PhoneNumber, Code HAVING COUNT(Code) > 1;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that means I must group by all those columns, no? I only want to count duplicates on the one column, not all of them.

Comment: Yup that will group all those column, you cannot do the `COUNT` in your `SELECT` if one of those column is not in your `GROUP BY` clause, yup that answer above will only display where code is greater than 1.

Comment: That's what I thought... so it doesn't really give the desired result.Thanks for trying though.

Comment: @hbob did you try it ? , if you want to do the `COUNT` without grouping those columns , you need also to remove those columns in your `SELECT` statement, and you  cannot count also inside the `SUB QUERY` because `IN` clause only need 1 returning column. you have 2 returning columns in your case.

Comment: Yes, so like I said, it doesn't do what I need ;)

Comment: @hbob maybe i can help you if you can show me sample data of your table and your desired result :)

Answer (score 1):

SQL 2015+:

`SELECT P.Id, P.Name, P.PhoneNumber, P.Code, Q.CodeCount from Person P
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Id, COUNT(Code) OVER(PARTITION BY Code) AS CodeCount
               FROM Person) AS Q
WHERE P.Id = Q.Id AND Q.CodeCount > 1`

Comment: SELECT Id, Name, PhoneNumber, Code, CodeCount from Person
INNER JOIN (SELECT Id, Code, COUNT(Code) AS CodeCount
               FROM Person
               GROUP BY Code
               HAVING COUNT(Code) > 1) AS A ON Id = A.Id

Comment: `In aggregate and grouping expressions, the SELECT clause can contain only aggregates and grouping expressions.`

Comment: You can get result aggregates functions inner join original table